# Can different users have same USER ID in MOSS 2007

Tags: sharepoint, moss, usergroups

Hi I am just curious to know whether different users can have same user ID in MOSS 2007.
I have two SharePoint groups with different set of permission levels. SharePointGroup1 is in root site. The subsite has unique permissions, i.e., it is having SharePointGroup2 with different set of users.

Is there any chance to have same user ID for different users in these two SharePoint Groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPUser.ID is only unique at the site collection level. AFAIK permission inheritance doesn't change how users are stored and id's assigned.

This can be a little confusing so to clarify you've got

Web Applications > Site Collections > Sites

for example :-

```
- Web App - Default Site Collection - Site A1 (http://server)
                                    - site A2 (http://server/someweb)
          - Another site Collection - Site B1 (http://server/sites/someweb)
                                    - Site B2 (http://server/sites/someotherweb)
```

So in this example

- A1 & A2 share the same user list so
  have unique user id's
- As do B1 & B2 -
- But the UserID's between A* to B* will not match

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your quick response.

Comment: Ryan, Can the SID be the same for different users in any case?

Comment: An aside, a SID (Security ID) is a Windows thing - SharePoint doesn't use them. But yes - you could have ID 12 for Carol in A1 and ID 12 for Ryan in B1 (opps just seen typo, edited q)

Comment: Thank You Ryan. It helpmed me a lot. Thanks Again!!

Comment: Ryan, Can the member IDs which the SharePoint uses be the same for different users in any case?

Comment: Yes - as I said above. Carol can be #12 in Site A1 and Ryan can be #12 in B1

Answer (score 0):

One user can be in several SharePoint Groups. If a user is in a parent site with SharePointGroup1 and also in a subsite with SharePointGroup2 (with its security inheritance broken between itself and the root site), then that should not be a problem. Two *different* users cannot have the same network ID.

Comment: Thanks Irish for your quick response.